# When to use Redis and when to use DataLoader in a GraphQL server setup

Tags: caching, redis, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I've been working on a GraphQL server for a while now and although I understand most of the aspects, I cannot seem to get a grasp on caching.

When it comes to caching, I see both DataLoader mentioned as well as Redis but it's not clear to me when I should use what and how I should use them.

I take it that DataLoader is used more on a field level to counter the n+1 problem? And I guess Redis is on a higher level then?

If anyone could shed some light on this, I would be most grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

DataLoader is *primarily* a means of batching requests to some data source. However, it does optionally utilize caching on a *per request* basis. This means, while executing the same GraphQL query, you only ever fetch a particular entity once. For example, we can call `load(1)` and `load(2)` concurrently and these will be batched into a single request to get two entities matching those ids. If another field calls `load(1)` later on while executing *the same request*, then that call will simply return the entity with ID `1` we fetched previously without making another request to our data source.

DataLoader's cache is specific to an individual request. Even if two requests are processed at the same time, they will not share a cache. DataLoader's cache does not have an expiration -- and it has no need to since the cache will be deleted once the request completes.

Redis is a key-value store that's used for caching, queues, PubSub and more. We can use it to provide [response caching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/caching), which would let us effectively bypass the resolver for one or more fields and use the cached value instead (until it expires or is invalidated). We can use it as a cache layer between GraphQL and the database, API or other data source -- for example, this is what [RESTDataSource](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources) does. We can use it as part of [a PubSub implementation](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions#pubsub-implementations) when implementing subscriptions.

DataLoader is a small library used to tackle a particular problem, namely generating too many requests to a data source. The alternative to using DataLoader is to fetch *everything* you need (based on the requested fields) at the root level and then letting the default resolver logic handle the rest. Redis is a key-value store that has a number of uses. Whether you need one or the other, or both, depends on your particular business case.

Comment: Data loaders do have cache invalidating mechanisms. Check `.clear(id)`, `clearAll()` apis in the official docs.

Comment: I saw your other reply and I understand what you mean by "individual request". In a single there can be mutation followed by queries and I guess this is when you use `clear` api. But I am wondering cant you also use the dataloader cache for multiple requests?? It could have similar caching effect as redis caching(I know redis caches the whole response. But the main bottleneck is fetching data from db, which is all cached in data loader. Its also more flexible. Cuz with redis if request changes slightly u have to fetch all over again)

Comment: @SihoonKim thanks for pointing out those methods, I've updated the answer. Please see [this issue](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader/issues/62) for additional discussion around what you're referring. As I stated in the original answer, Redis is not exclusively used for response caching -- it's just a key value store, which means it can be used for a number of things. If you want a way to cache individual query results, you can use it for that too. The bottom line is DataLoader is was not intended to be used across multiple requests. Can you do it? Sure. However, it won't scale well.